# eajaxupload for Yii always "failed"

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

We are currently trying to use the extension eajaxupload for Yii but it seems to be outputting failed everytime we try to upload a file.

We have tried

a) editing the file / minimum file sizes

b) playing around with the file path (may still be incorrect, if anyone knows what the path for locally using in xampp would be, let us know. Our uploads folder is in the root of the project.)

c) changing the htiaccess php file

d) permissions

we just don't know if the code itself is appearing wrong.

controller

```
/* UPLOADER */
    public function actionUpload(){
        Yii::import("ext.EAjaxUpload.qqFileUploader");
//        $folder = '/uploads/';
//        $folder=Yii::getPathOfAlias() .'/upload/';
        $folder=Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/uploads/';
        $allowedExtensions = array("jpg","png");//array("jpg","jpeg","gif","exe","mov" and etc...
        $sizeLimit = 10 * 1024 * 1024;// maximum file size in bytes
        $uploader = new qqFileUploader($allowedExtensions, $sizeLimit);
        $result = $uploader->handleUpload($folder);
//        $return = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES);
// 
//        $fileSize=filesize($folder.$result['filename']);//GETTING FILE SIZE
//        $fileName=$result['filename'];//GETTING FILE NAME
// 
//        echo $return;// it's array

        $result = $uploader->handleUpload($folder);

        $fileSize=filesize($folder.$result['filename']);//GETTING FILE SIZE
        $fileName=$result['filename'];//GETTING FILE NAME
        $result=htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES);

        echo $result;// it's array
    }
```

View

```
*$this->widget('ext.EAjaxUpload.EAjaxUpload',
                array(
                    'id'=>'uploadFile',
                    'config'=>array(
                        'action'=>'/upload/',
//                        'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('controllers/uploads/'),
                        'allowedExtensions'=>array("jpg","png"),//array("jpg","jpeg","gif","exe","mov" and etc...
                        'sizeLimit'=>10*1024*1024,// maximum file size in bytes
                        //'minSizeLimit'=>10*1024*1024,// minimum file size in bytes
                        'onComplete'=>"js:function(id, fileName, responseJSON){ alert(fileName); }",
                        'messages'=>array(
                            'typeError'=>"{file} has invalid extension. Only {extensions} are allowed.",
                            'sizeError'=>"{file} is too large, maximum file size is {sizeLimit}.",
                            'minSizeError'=>"{file} is too small, minimum file size is {minSizeLimit}.",
                            'emptyError'=>"{file} is empty, please select files again without it.",
                            'onLeave'=>"The files are being uploaded, if you leave now the upload will be cancelled."
                        ),
                        'showMessage'=>"js:function(message){ alert(message); }"

                    )*
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem long ago. 
You have to make sure that:

- you get the local path, not url (Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot')).
- the $sizeLimit has to be less than the php options 'post_max_size' and 'upload_max_size'. You can check their values with ini_get(*variable*) and convert it to Bytes.
- Also noticed that you are trying to upload the file twice.
- If none of them work post the error message that you are getting.

Comment: So would :    $folder=Yii::getPathOfAlias() .'/upload/'; 

then 'action'=>'/upload/',  be the correct way to format this? Still having no luck! we were initially getting a 403 error then have moved over to a 400.

Comment: Have u tried Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot') ?
Can you print the full path that you are getting?

Comment: Yep I'm sure webroot was the first thing we tried when using getpathofalias. The current path that seems to being output is /application/uploads/images/

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your action is wrong in the

```
'config'=>array(
   'action'=>'/upload/',
```

If you are uploading to the `public function actionUpload()`

then your action must be 'upload/upload' because the ConrollerName/ActionName must match the 'action' in your widget

```
'config'=>array(
       'action'=> Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/upload/upload',
```

or

```
'config'=>array(
   'action'=>$this->createUrl('upload/upload')
```

Take a look at this too: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

To update this, it wouldn't work on local server Xampp on MAC.

It worked on our live dev server, but not the live server. Seems the extension is server dependant. There is a lack of documentation and I imagine there is a fix, but it answers a lot of questions how the code is fine but not working.

Comment: I also having problem in live server,  the ajax call after choosing image does not reach to action url. :(. @Alex  will you please share me, how did  you solve it?

Comment: we did not solve what caused the issue unfortunately. We uploaded to our live server where it worked and got lucky that it did! if it's possible for you to host elsewhere you might be in more luck.